Any leads on how the choice of shape functions influence finite element stability?
I have seen something similar in the publication "The BR1 Scheme is Stable for the Compressible Navier–Stokes Equations" where the arguments for stability rely on the use of Legendre-Gauss-Lobatto polynomials. Also in the book "Nodal Discontinuous Galerkin Methods" by Jan S. Hesthaven and Tim Warburton you can see bits and pieces of the analysis of Gauss vs Gauss-Lobatto. This analysis is mostly driven by the need to overcome aliasing errors and I have only seen in in the context of DG.
I am interested in this because I am seeing the sort of stability analysis you find in the finite difference space and not the standard functional analysis type of stability you would find in FE where it's "Choose $ V_h \in P(k) $ ... Has anyone generalised this type of "full discrete" stability analysis to include shape functions? I was suspecting to find something if I looked at the IGA literature on this, because well they might have to ask themselves "what sort of errors does my curved mesh introduce to my fully discrete scheme?", but I didn't find any leads.
So,
Are there any works generalised stability analysis to include shape functions/curved meshes/mixed elements? Maybe people who do FEEC or work on shell-type FEM?
I hope I am making sense. Any hints or directions are appreciated.

I dont understand your question. Are you asking about why "functional analysis-like" stability estimates are telling us something about stability? The Finite-Difference stability formulations have to be different, as they deal with discrete sequences of point values, rather than piecewise-polynomial functions, but they express the same idea. In the case of linear, elliptic problems one can in many cases inherit the stability for the exact solution into the discrete setting. Stability analysis for different element types is usually done in papers that develop these element types.

"Stability analysis for different element types is usually done in papers that develop these element types", yes but I am hoping to find a mathematical technique that generalises these things.
